# Detect a new record was added to cassandra table

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a requirement: when a new comment is posted, i want to get all previous comment's owner id and send a notification.

Problem here is how will i know that a new comment was added to cassandra table. What will the solution for this kind of requirement ?

Comment: This sounds like something you should do in your application, event triggered by user posting a comment, not the event of the table being updated..

Comment: Cassandra 2.0 & later version supports [trigger](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-0-prototype-triggers-support) which would help you...

Comment: is trigger idle for a situation where very frequent writes happening ?

Comment: I don't found any benchmark reports over cassandra trigger. Better you can have your own benchmarks with your business needs to test performance, assertion for any missing trigger and order of execution of trigger in a multi-threaded write application.  Without huge change in the architecture it is the only way to achieve your goal. But the consequence depends upon your benchmark results.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use only cassandra, without changes, it's impossible. 
With changes, you have three options:

1. You can use cassandra as embedded service in java. Here is a simple and short how to: http://prettyprint.me/prettyprint.me/2010/02/14/running-cassandra-as-an-embedded-service/index.html
2. You can create a wrapper for your cassandra connection. An Application which handles the Cassandra Connection and is available via API for your other application.
3. Cassandra has a trigger functionality. (Never used it and never heard that someone is using it)

I prefer the second solution. Here are the reasons why:

- It's simpler to create.
- You can handler all your views in this application.
- You can validate the input, resolve relations, logging data etc.
- You can simply push the new added comment to kafka or another message queue.

This could be a setup:

Create a new comment -> call a backend api -> call the cassandra database interface -> push a new message to kafka -> send the data to all kafka consumer